correct syntax to access a template variable specialization
assume a template variable in data.h:
template <class T>
struct Data
{
    Data() = delete;
    Data(T initValue) : value(initValue){}
    T value;
};

template<class T>
extern Data<T> data;

there is a specialization definition of this variable for int in data_def.cpp:
#include "data.h"
template<>
Data<int> data<int>{55};

usage in main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "data.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << data<int>.value << "\n";
    return 0;
}

full project on godbolt
The code works on GCC but clang complains:
warning: instantiation of variable 'data' required here, but no definition is available [-Wundefined-var-template].
Probably it expects a declaration of a template variable specialization.
What is the right way (according to the standard) to define a template variable specialization in one translation unit and use it in a different one?
If a declaration of a variable specialization is necessary what is the syntax for this?
In standard I did not find an answer.

I can use only C++17 (if it matters).
A tempting syntax template<> extern Data<int> data<int>; is wrong (GCC does not accept it and clang devs are going to do the same)
update:
@Oersted and @user12002570 suggested a WA with inline. It's not a full solution but a valid WA

Why not extern Data<int> data; ? I.e. a regular extern variable declaration. It seems almost obvious in this case, so could you have simplified too much perhaps?

just in case it's really a template variable you're needing, it worked with https://godbolt.org/z/zTKc6aYah (but I'm not sure it's the right way to do. I'm not sure either you have to declare the primary variable template extern.

Ah, I think that following your logic https://godbolt.org/z/v99aKf49h is better: data<int> is specialized and declared extern in a header file and you can define it in a source file. It does not need to be declared in data.h, you can have a dedicated header for specializations.

@Oersted i have many TU where i use data so your approach is not applicable https://godbolt.org/z/7ojPTGozf

@Oersted about extern. it's written in data.h  that template<> extern Data data; is wrong syntax. gcc does not like it

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica i tried instantiation instead of specialization but it did not work for me

I may have not been clear in my question. Why do you want the declaration to be a template declaration at all? Why not a regular declaration of a variable, whose type is a regular type (that is instantiated from a template)?

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica i see (i misunderstood you). the main reason - there might be several instances of data variable for different types. i write a library that declares a template variable and in the client code there might be several instances for different user types

I didn't see for gcc, sorry. It's better then with inline: https://godbolt.org/z/39jGbrxdf

@Alexander Just use inline with c++17 as shown here.

@Oersted i'd like to avoid inline in this case. but let me try (the real Data struct has static members so I need to check it)

@Alexander You can use inilne irrespective of static members. It is the cleanest solution with modern c++.

@Oersted +user12002570
inline works. thanks, it does not answer exactly the question but it's a valid WA


If a declaration of a variable specialization is necessary what is the syntax for this?

You can just use inline in the definition of the specialization in the header file. That way you won't need to define it in a separate source file. Demo
Change data.h to:
#pragma once

template <class T>
struct Data
{
    Data() = delete;
    Data(T initValue) : value(initValue){}
    T value;
};

template<class T>
extern Data<T> data;
//---------vvvvvv--------------------------inline added here
template<> inline  Data<int> data<int>{55};


